# Hover background image change on checkbox span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a way to change the background image when hovering over my checkbox span (I had to build it this way due to firefox problems).

Whenever I add a :hover state it just ignores it?

I have created a replica of my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/vf21xxba/

Each of the divs have will have a different icon by id and the images will be different on hover too.

```
label.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {     display:none; }

label.checkbox span{    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;   display:inline-block;   border-radius: 100px;   transition: all 0.5s;   cursor: pointer;    width: 75px;    height: 75px;   background:#262626;  
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%;            }

label.checkbox span#pa {    background-image: url('../img/icons/party-animal.png'); }

label.checkbox :checked + span#pa {   background-color: #ea2e49; }


<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value=".pa" id="pa" class="initPa"><span id="pa"></span></label>
```

So like the 'checked' sate i need to add a hover sate for each span with an ID with a different background image.

Comment: If I add 
label.checkbox:hover span#pa {
 background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
}
It works properly. Don't see the problem

Comment: I honestly had originally tried doing this? Maybe I was having some caching issues or something

Comment: It's possible. You can also try reverting your code in editor and compare it. Maybe you had some syntax error, or typo.

Comment: Deffo a caching issue, I thought I was going mad over a simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the + out

https://jsfiddle.net/vf21xxba/3/

```
label.checkbox :checked + span#pa, label.checkbox:hover span#pa {
  background-color: #ea2e49;
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/zerode/plump/128/Search-icon.png'); 
}
```

Comment: I think the question is "background-image change", so this is not complete answer.

Comment: It seems to be better now. Even though original answer could've been ok for the person who asked, it's better to have correct answer for the people who have the same problem later.